# abstract method vs subclass-only methods

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

Recently I read that an abstract method essentially creates one marked for inheritance and that is block-less, awaiting subclass specialization. Well I ask this:
What is the difference between creating an abstract method, allowing its inheritance, and making a subclass version, and having no corresponding superclass method, and one only defined by/in the subclass.
By the principles of overriding, shouldn't a subclass object automatically use a subclass method, and if there is no corresponding superclass method, a subclass object would always use a subclass method.
What is the purpose of creating an abstract method as opposed to just a standard method with no superclass counterpart.

My knowledge may be completely flawed and skewing my perception :-)
any and all help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has to do with [Polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming); the ability for one class to act like another.

Take the example of having an abstract class called `Animal` which is subclassed to `Dog` and `Fish`. If in the `Animal` class we have an abstract method `move()` then both `Dog` and `Fish` will be forced to implement the `move()` method.

```
public class Animal {
    public abstract void move();
}

public class Dog extends Animal {
    public void move() {
        System.out.println("walk");
    }
}

public class Fish extends Animal {
    public void move() {
        System.out.println("swim");
    }
}
```

Furthermore, if we then have a helper method somewhere:

```
public static void moveTheAnimal(Animal a) {
    a.move();
}
```

Then we know that whatever concrete class (subclass) is provided, a `move()` method is *guaranteed* to be defined.

If on the otherhand there was no abstract method `move()` in the `Animal` class, we would need a `moveTheDog(Dog d)` and  `moveTheFish(Fish f)` etc. for each possible animal.

Answer (score 0):

Superclass may delegate part of its duties to subclasses via abstract methods. The advantage of this is that superclass would contain only the generic reusable logic and more concrete details of implementation would be pushed down the inheritance tree, to the subclasses.

In this situation, superclass still may need to access some methods *as if* they are already implemented. This is why you need to have abstract bodyless methods defined in the superclass — otherwise it won't be able to refer to them!

For example, superclass may handle processing of data, whereas concrete subclasses may handle data input from various sources. In this case superclass and subclass may look like this:

```
class DataProcessor {
    public void doWork() {
        Data data = readData();

        processData(data);
    }

    public abstract Data readData();  // this method is here and marked as abstract to make sure that:
                                      // 1. child classes never fail to implement it;
                                      // 2. parent class have a possibility to refer to the method that he is not actually implementing;
                                      // 3. users of parent class have a possibility to refer to the method that parent is not capable of implementing.
}

class FileSystemDataProcessor extends DataProcessor {
    public Data readData();
        // handle data reading from the file system
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The intent for an abstract method is to tell the developer that you expect every subclass to have an implementation of the method. Here's an example below:

```
public class Animal {
    public abstract void move(); // you expect that every animal will be able to move
}

public class Bird extends Animal {
    @Override
    public void move() { ... }

    public void fly() { ... } // Birds can fly
}

public class Dog extends Animal {
    @Override
    public void move() { ... }
}

public class Pig extends Animal {
    public void oink();
} // COMPILE ERROR
```

Then, when you have a function that takes an `Animal` object, you are also implying that the function won't be doing anything that is `Bird`, `Dog`, or `Pig` specific.

If you provided no abstract method declaration in the `Animal` superclass such a function will not compile as it has no guarantee that any of its subclasses has a `move()` method.